# yii url manager. urls in path format

Tags: yii, url-routing

I've been developing web application based on Yii framework.

I've faced with troubles on trying to make sef urls.

What I have:

1. config is set up.

   'urlManager'=>array(
       'urlFormat'=>'path',
       'showScriptName'=>false,
       'rules'=>array(
   // rules go here
       )
   )
2. This is code which is used for tesing:

`echo $this->createUrl('site/test', array('help'=>'me')`

`$this` - is controller.

If I'm living 'rules' array in config empty I'm getting this `/site/test/help/me`. I expected this.

If

```
'rules'=>array(
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
)
```

I'm getting `/site/test?help=me` which is also expected.

But if

```
'rules'=>array(
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<help:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>/<help>',
)
```

I'm still getting `/site/test?help=me`. I expected to see `/site/test/me`

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the order of rules and remove `<help>`. It will be automatically added to action. So your rules should look like this:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<help:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

Order of rules matters. You need to put the most detailed one first.

Regards